# Не удается перейти по ссылке на другой сайт на Nuxt

Tags: javascript, node.js, nuxt.js

Хочу перейти по ссылке на другой сайт, но Nuxt этого не позволяет:

```
<nuxt-link to="https://www.google.com/"></nuxt-link>
```

Будет так:
`localhost:3000/https://www.google.com/`,

Как перейти на другой сайт?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Никак через компонент. `NuxtLink` - это компонент для перехода по внутренним ссылкам роутера.

Если Вы хотите сделать переход на внешний сайт, используйте обычный тег для ссылок из HTML:

```
<a href="https://www.google.com/"></a>
```

Comment: спасибо, сработало